# Timeout/synchronisation logic in UART communication

Tags: serial-port, synchronization, logic, uart, serial-communication

**Background:**
I use UART for communication between two devices (with different OSs, one with Linux and one with Windows). I have an application on Windows, as master (sending commands) and an application in Linux as acting and responding application. It will do corresponding operations and give response.

**Windows app:** Application will send a command and wait for the response. If Linux has not responded within some (say, 10 seconds), come out of wait, notifying the user a timeout error, (and send the next command by user).

**Linux app:** Application will wait for the command. Process it (say, for 5 seconds max), and then send response to Windows.

**Problem:** If due to any error/issue, Linux responds after Windows app's timeout (say, 15 seconds), Windows application has already aborted the command thinking it's timed out, and sent the next command. The response of first command is being treated as response for current one, which is not correct.

**Solution:** I thought of appending the command byte as first byte in Linux response to check/verify in Windows application (that whether the response is for current command or not) and ignore if invalid. But this too has limitations that, if both the commands are same, there will be a mismatch again.

What other logic I can implement to solve this?

Comment: The command should include a unique ID, such as a sequence number or time stamp.  The response must include this ID.  I've used a time stamp (e.g. the seconds of the day) because that makes it trivial to compute the round-trip elapsed time.

Comment: Thanks @sawdust! That looks like good idea. I will check this and get back.. Thanks! :)